# How do I call abstract lightning component controller's method from a component which is extending it?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

So here is my parent lightning component controller method...

```
doInit({
 getParameter : function(component, name) {
    return (window.location.search.match(new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]+)')) || [, null])[1];
}})
```

Now I want to call this method in a component controller, which is extending it.

The extending Component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" extends="c:Parent" access="global">
```

The extending Component Controller:

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var param = c.getParameter(component, 'abc'); // This is where I think I'm wrong.
}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say you have a helper method `getParameter` in the abstract component from the child component which is extending it you should do

```
this.getParameter();
```

from the child component's helper. you can't access the abstract components controller methods but you can access the helper methods.

Read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/oo_whats_inherited.htm)